# Java Runtime Exception Message :: What Do Brackets Mean?

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error, message, brackets

my company has a custom Java app that is recently crashing when we try to run it.  Here's the stacktrace when it blows up:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at com.mycompany.fileUtility.checkFiles.validateData(fileUtility.java:112) ~[wonderApp.jar:?]
        at com.mycompany.wonderApp.BuildConfig.<init>(BuildConfig.java:78) ~[wonderApp.jar:?]
        at com.mycompany.wonderApp.ConfigMonitor.build(ConfigMonitor.java:698) [wonderApp.jar:?]
        at com.mycompany.wonderApp.MainDriver.Main(MainDriver.java:18) [wonderApp.jar:?]
```

My question is:  What is that information in brackets?  i.e. `~[?:1.8.0_345]` for the Java library functions, and `~[wonderApp.jar:?]` for the custom code stuff?  What does the colon mean?  What does the `?` signify?  For that matter, what about the `~` outside the brackets?

FYI, our platform is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9.  Our version of Java is:

```
[me@server01 tmp]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_345"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_345-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.345-b01, mixed mode)
[me@server01 tmp]$
```

Thank you.

Comment: As a side note: the active support for java8 ended over a year ago. I would recommend switching to java17 as even java11's support ends in 5 months.

Comment: @f1sh Yeah, that's a really good point.  My company is really slow to upgrade, but I didn't realize that we were THAT behind the times...  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's using [logback](https://logback.qos.ch) as the logging implementation, and the pattern layout for the log message is dumping the exception stack as described in [this table](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord):

> At the end of each stack frame of the exception, a string consisting of the jar file containing the relevant class followed by the "Implementation-Version" as found in that jar's manifest will be added. [...] If the information is uncertain, then the class packaging data will be preceded by a tilde, i.e. the '~' character.

Comment: Yes!  You hit the nail on the head!  When I asked my colleagues, they told me that the stacktrace was taken from org.apache.logging.log4j.  The specific method that was called is here:  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#error-org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Throwable-  Thank you!